# What is this procedure called for angle radians?

Tags: trigonometry

So, my lecturer says that $-\cos(\frac{\pi}{8}) = \cos(\frac{9\pi}{8})$.

What did he do to get that?

Please recommend a source where I can brush up on my knowledge of angles.

Comment: You should check carefully what you say your lecturer says. That identity is wrong, as the left side is positive whereas the right side is negative.

Comment: You're correct. He did put a minus sign. @Joanpemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite true, the two are not equal. They are opposites of each other. $cos(x)=-\cos(x+\pi)$ holds. The fact that they are opposites is not a property of radians, this is a property of the cosine function.

It is true that an angle that is $x$ radians is also an angle of $x+2\pi$ radians. This is because $2\pi$ radians is a full circle, so if you measure an angle but travel around the entire circle first, you add $2\pi$ to the measurement. This is also true for degree measurements: an angle of $x$ degrees is also an angle of $x+360$ degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Using the basic identity $\;\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y\;$ , you obtain

$$\cos\frac{9\pi}8=\cos\left(\frac\pi8+\pi\right)=\cos\frac\pi8\cdot\cos\pi-\sin\frac\pi8\cdot\sin\pi=$$

$$=\cos\frac\pi8\cdot(-1)-\sin\frac\pi8\cdot0=-\cos\frac\pi8$$